update to 24.04 lts from 22.04 lts stopped due to lost wifi, unable to restart
I was on ubuntu 22.04 LTS (jammy jellyfish), and wanted to now update to 24.04 LTS (noble numbat). I did so using update-manager. Mid installation, the machine lost wifi connection, the installer failed and printed a message that it would go back to the previous state, but now nothing is working. The update-manager command is not available, neither is nmcli or silimar. I do not have sudo privileges anymore (unable to resolve host). I turned off the machine and can only boot into the tty. Trying from there to install update-manager fails due to "unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages".
So, in thinking i did everything correct and by the book, now my machine is at a stage where I have no idea how to resolve the issues.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Of course you backed up all data before the attempt. It is time to reinstall from fresh.

I did, luckily, so there isn't that much id loose. But really no other way? Or perhaps just the easiest way?

You could spend months trying to fix issues and errors and still never be 100 percent. So realistically, no, to reinstall is a relatively quick fix.

Wild shot dpkg -l | grep systemd-resolved please.

Look at your apt sources. If they are 22.04 sources, then run do-release-upgrade again. If they are 24.04 sources, then run sudo apt full-upgrade. Sometimes it's recoverable, sometimes not. One hopes you remembered to uninstall your PPAs and other non-Ubuntu software; those are the most common cause of broken release-upgrades. Including actual, complete output in your question increases the probability of useful advice.
